# Regex with multiple repetation

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I have difficult time with regex right now.

I am able to debug the regex in Regexbuddy but somehow it is not working in C#.net.

For example.

My Input string:-

```
--8W1_805_431____0210_A01_0002_L--;%{PE}%R  
8.2.24,%MKUKATPBASIS,%CCOMMENT,%VNORMAL,%P 2: --8W1_805_431____0210_A01_0002_L--
;ENDFOLD  

;FOLD PTP SG003920 Vel=100 % PDAT5 ServoGun=8 Cont=OPN Part=2.65 mm WeldTimer=WTDAT1 Tool[1]:zc1 Base[1]:510wz1;%{PE}%R 4.1.25,%MKUKATPSERVOTECH,%CSpotTC,%VPTP,%P 1:PTP, 2:SG003920, 3:, 5:100, 7:PDAT5, 9:1, 11:1, 13:OPN, 15:2.65, 18:1, 21:0, 24:0, 27:5, 30:0, 33:WTDAT1
$BWDSTART=FALSE
PDAT_ACT=PPDAT5
FDAT_ACT=FSG003920
BAS(#PTP_PARAMS,100)
EG_SPOT_POINT_NAME[]="SG003920"
EG_EXTAX_ACTIVE=EG_SERVOGUN_EXAXIS[1]
EG_THICKNESS=2.65
EG_GUN_FORCE=1
EG_COMP_HELP=0
EG_COMPENSATE_PATH=0
EG_PROGRAM_NUMBER=003920
EG_HELPPOINT=EG_CHTIP(XSG003920)
PTP EG_HELPPOINT 
EG_APPROX_OPEN=FALSE
CMD=#SPOT
EG_SPOT_POINT=EG_HELPPOINT
EG_SPOT( WTWTDAT1 )  
PTP EG_HELPPOINT C_DIS
CMD=#STOP_POINT_END
EG_SPOT_POINT=EG_HELPPOINT
EG_SPOT( )

  ; --8W1_112_431____0210_A01_0001_L--;%{PE}%R 8.2

;FOLD PTP SG003918 Vel=100 % PDAT7 ServoGun=1 Cont=OPN Part=2.65 mm WeldTimer=WTDAT2 Tool[1]:zc1 Base[1]:510wz1;%{PE}%R 4.1.25,%MKUKATPSERVOTECH,%CSpotTC,%VPTP,%P 1:PTP, 2:SG003918, 3:, 5:100, 7:PDAT7, 9:1, 11:1, 13:OPN, 15:2.65, 18:1, 21:0, 24:0, 27:5, 30:0, 33:WTDAT2
$BWDSTART=FALSE
PDAT_ACT=PPDAT7
FDAT_ACT=FSG003918
BAS(#PTP_PARAMS,100)
EG_SPOT_POINT_NAME[]="SG003918"
EG_EXTAX_ACTIVE=EG_SERVOGUN_EXAXIS[1]
EG_THICKNESS=2.65
EG_GUN_FORCE=1
EG_COMP_HELP=0
EG_COMPENSATE_PATH=0
EG_PROGRAM_NUMBER=003918
EG_HELPPOINT=EG_CHTIP(XSG003918)
PTP EG_HELPPOINT 
EG_APPROX_OPEN=FALSE
CMD=#SPOT
EG_SPOT_POINT=EG_HELPPOINT
EG_SPOT( WTWTDAT2 )
PTP EG_HELPPOINT C_DIS
CMD=#STOP_POINT_END
EG_SPOT_POINT=EG_HELPPOINT
EG_SPOT( )
;ENDFOLD


Regex Pattern:- --(?<PName>8W.*?)--.*?(?<MType>PTP|LIN).*?(?<PointNa>SG)
```

The output has to be like this for the group PName.

8W1_112_431____0210_A01_0001_L

8W1_805_431____0210_A01_0002_L

As I run this regex in c# its returns always false.

Please any one guide me what is wrong over here.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Pattern which i have used is: Regex Pattern:-  --(?<PName>8W.*?)--.*?(?<MType>PTP|LIN).*?(?<PointNa>SG)

Comment: Add the `(?s)` at the beginning. Or use `RegexOptions.Singleline`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew why  use "RegexOptions.Singleline" I have a multiple line in input string

Comment: It is C#, not Ruby, so `(?s)` - a "singleline" modifier - makes the `.` to match a newline. Do not pay attention to the naming, it is always misleading.

Comment: See http://ideone.com/loBDnB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is easy: add the `(?s)` at the beginning. Or use `RegexOptions.Singleline` flag with your `Regex.Match`.

See [IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/loBDnB)

You need to understand the role of [regex modifiers in .NET regex](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regexoptions(v=vs.110).aspx):

- `RegexOptions.Singleline` - *Specifies single-line mode. Changes the meaning of the dot (`.`) so it matches every character (instead of every character except `\n`). For more information, see the "Single-line Mode" section in the [Regular Expression Options](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yd1hzczs(v=vs.110).aspx) topic.*
- `RegexOptions.Multiline` - *Multiline mode. Changes the meaning of `^` and `$` so they match at the beginning and end, respectively, of any line, and not just the beginning and end of the entire string. For more information, see the "Single-line Mode" section in the [Regular Expression Options](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yd1hzczs(v=vs.110).aspx) topic.*

Also, see [Difference between regular expression modifiers 'm' and 's'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/918806/difference-between-regular-expression-modifiers-m-and-s)